# com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I am trying to access Cloud Firestore from my android project.
I am just following the guide provided by Google -> https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library

```
val firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
            .setProjectId("my_project_id")
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
            .build()

val db: Firestore = firestoreOptions.service
```

When firestoreOptions.service is used, I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testing/com.example.testing.ui.activity.MainActivity}: com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3645)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:358)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:79)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:64)
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544)
        at com.example.testing.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:85)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:142)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:88)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:80) 
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:564) 
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:358) 
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:79) 
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71) 
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:64) 
        at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:544) 
        at com.example.testing.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:85) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8305) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8284) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1417) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3626) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp, grpc-netty, or grpc-netty-shaded artifact
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider.provider(ManagedChannelProvider.java:45)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:351)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.$r8$lambda$uvhXwQKV1b6n5wSR9q5C4LYdHSs(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.createSingleChannel(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(ChannelPool.java:107)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:85)
```

Here is the firestore dependency I'm using in my build.gradle

```
implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:3.9.3')
```

I have tried adding the grpc dependencies to my project as suggested by various sources...

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.30.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.30.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.30.0'
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-api:1.44.1'
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I don't know anything about grpc.

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ, check that Gradle is actually downloading any of the required library options into your External Libraries -which btw should be just one of those (I recommend you grpc-netty-shaded) If it's not there, run a Gradle build and If it still not there afterwards Invalidate cache/Restart your IDE

Comment: Tried that and it looks like everything got downloaded. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with Google Cloud including Firestore but I'm not a Java developer and I'm almost entirely unfamiliar with Gradle so please excuse the naive code below. The following works for me.

I used Cloud Shell with `--authorize-session` as this provides:

- Auth'd w/ Google Cloud:
- Java
- Gradle

```bash
gcloud cloud-shell ssh --authorize-session
```

Then:

```bash
Q="75904235"

PROJECT="$(whoami)-$(date +%y%m%d)-${Q}"
REGION="us-west1" # Or your preferred

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud app create \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud firestore databases create \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```bash
mkdir -p ${Q}/src/main/java/stackoverflow
cd ${Q}
gradle
```

With `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "application"
}

apply plugin : "java" 

ext {
   javaMainClass = "stackoverflow.FirestoreExample"
}

application {
    mainClassName = javaMainClass
}

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:3.9.3"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.54.0"
}
```

And:
`FirestoreExample.java`:

```
package stackoverflow;

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteResult;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.*;

public class FirestoreExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Replace with value of ${PROJECT}
    String projectId = "...";

    try {
      FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
        FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
          .setProjectId(projectId)
          .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
          .build();
      Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();

      DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("alovelace");
      Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
      data.put("first", "Ada");
      data.put("last", "Lovelace");
      data.put("born", 1815);
      ApiFuture<WriteResult> result = docRef.set(data);
      System.out.println("Update time : " + result.get().getUpdateTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```